# 20.04 Brother Printer

Tags: 20.04, printing, brother

I have a Brother hl-2700cn printer that works with 14.04.

Using the System.Administration.Printers GUI in 20.04 to install it does not work. I can not print anything. Not  even a test page. All that comes out is "ERROR NAME: \n undefined" I used the same procedure with 14.04 without a problem.

The Brother printer site has an install package which is unable to find a driver package.

The only visible difference between the 2 versions of Ubuntu is that 14.04 Make and model is "Brother HL-2700CN Foomatic.Postscript" and 20.04 is "... BR-Script3". Using the Change button opens a search that never finds anything.

How can I make my printer work?

Comment: Download the driver install tool from Brother themselves.  It was released this year.  https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2700cn_all&os=128  It is up to the manufacturer if they support linux or not.

Comment: The printer worked fine until I installed 20.04 without any need to refer to support.brother.com. It still works with the old 14.04 version that I have on a separate partition.

Comment: Again, it is up to the manufacturer of the printer if they support Linux or not.  If they have had to create a driver for it to work in 20.04 then they did.  But you have to try to install it.  Driver support can change between versions of Ubuntu.  Just because it works in a previous version does not mean that the driver is carried over to the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Open a terminal and run:

```
  cd ~/Downloads

  wget https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/openprinting-ppds-postscript-brother_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo dpkg -i openprinting-ppds-postscript-brother_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb

  sudo apt-get install -f

  sudo apt-get install system-config-printer

  system-config-printer
```

And see if your printer appears

Comment: Didn't work. There is only a BR-Script3 driver. No sign of the Foomatic.Postscrit driver. In all, no change.